# Is NetBeans Visual Web Pack disabled?

Tags: netbeans, wysiwyg

I want to use NetBeans Visual Web Pack as is showed [here](https://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/visualwebdev/) but I cannot find any source of download nor plugin, anything, is it discontinued or what?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, went to take micro walk around the house and when I sat down again found [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/VisualWebSupport) looking around.